# ADO Testing - How to create a test scenario

Tags: testing, azure-devops

Is it possible to link multiple requirements to a single test case to create a test scenario? I am aware it is possible to link several test cases together to create a teat plan however the test lead on one of my projects does not want to draft single test cases.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. A test case could contain several requirements and several links. Also, a test plan could contain several test cases. So what you want is completely achievable. And your test lead should not worry about that. Here is [a document about creating test plans and test suites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/create-a-test-plan?view=azure-devops).